# How to make an empty datatype or conditional field in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

I'd like to write code in which some inputs don't exist. I'd like to create a structure which contains those params (among other things). How can I do it? I tried to use generate, define an empty struct (`typedef struct {} empty_t`) and 0-size array (`logic foo[0]`) but all my attempts failed as syntax errors.

EDIT: I'm trying to do something like (simplified):

```
module foo(clk, data_in, opt_data_in);
    parameter USE_OPT_IN = 1;

    input logic clk;
    input logic data_in;
    input logic opt_data_in;

    typedef struct packed {
        logic data_in;
        // Since it's stored in on-chip RAM I'd like it
        // to be as small as possible
        if (USE_OPT_IN != 0)
            logic opt_data_in;
    } ram_entry_t;
    ram_entry_t my_ram[4096];

    always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
        ram_entry_t new_entry;
        new_entry.data_in = data_in;
        if (USE_OPT_IN != 0)
            new_entry.opt_data_in = opt_data_in;
        my_ram[$random() % 4096] = new_entry;
    end
endmodule
```

This of course does not compile.

EDIT2: Above is simplified example. There is over 7 optional fields and coding 128 structs seems unreasonable - compared with just using unstructured bit field.

Comment: When you say 'Inputs' can you explain inputs to what?

Comment: To module. From the outside they will just not be connected to anything (`'Z`) as I don't think I can make optional inputs but I run into problem when I wanted to actually store them somewhere. Right now I'm thinking about just using a bitfield and manually pack the data but it would be nice if I could do something more HL.

Comment: do you have a code example?

Comment: @Serge Here you go.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an optional port or empty datatype. The code inside the module that references the port has to make sense for any situation.

There are a few things you can do

1. You can assign a default value to an input port that will be used if left unconnected.
2. You can parameterize a port type to use different structures with different number of fields. Again, the code inside the module must work for any datatype. This usually means casting the input to a known type inside the module.
3. You can also use an variable sized array if all the input types are the same.

Comment: Ok. It looks like I need to concatenate useful fields manually due to external requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only suggestion is to use a TYPE as a parameter to the module where the latter could be a struct with or without the field. You will also need a genarate block unless you can work with interfaces or classes. Here is a skeleton way of doing it. It would probably require yet another OPT param though for generate block. Sorry, i have not try to compile it.

```
module foo#(parameter type TYPE = int, parameter bit OPT = 1) 
       (clk, data_in, opt_data_in);
   input logic clk;
   input logic data_in;
   input logic out_data_in;

   TYPE my_ram[4096];

   if (OPT) begin
    always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
       TYPE new_entry;
       new_entry.data_in <= data_in;
       new_entry.opt_data_in <= opt_data_in;
       my_ram[$random() % 4096] <= new_entry;
    end
  else begin
    always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
       TYPE new_entry;
       new_entry.data_in <= data_in;
       my_ram[$random() % 4096] <= new_entry;
    end

  end
endmodule
```

now you can instantiate you module with different classes:

```
typedef struct packed {
    logic data_in;       
    logic opt_data_in;
} ram_entry_full_t;
typedef struct packed {
    logic data_in;       
} ram_entry_short_t;

foo#(ram_entry_full_t, 1) foo_full(..);
foo#(ram_entry_short_t, 0) foo_short(..);
```

Comment: The problem is that this quickly becomes unreasonable. If I have 7 fields this is 128 structs I would need to implement. It's easier at this point to do:
`function int get_size();
    return 1 + USE_OPT_IN
endfunction
function logic get_data_opt_offset();
    return 0;
endfunction
function logic get_data_offset();
    return  get_data_opt_offset() + USE_OPT_IN;
endfunction
...
typedef logic [get_size() - 1] entry;
`

Comment: for get_size you can use `$bits()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'll build on @Serge answer. If you want to make your RAM entry types external to the module and use them as parameters, you can do away with the `USE_OPT_IN` parameter altogether, as this is redundant:

```
typedef struct packed {
  logic data_in;       
  logic opt_data_in;
} ram_entry_full_t;

typedef struct packed {
  logic data_in;       
} ram_entry_short_t;


module foo #(parameter type TYPE = int) (clk, data_in, opt_data_in);
  input logic clk;
  input logic data_in;
  input logic out_data_in;

  TYPE my_ram[4096];

  if (TYPE == type(ram_entry_full_t)) begin
    always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
      TYPE new_entry;
      new_entry.data_in <= data_in;
      new_entry.opt_data_in <= opt_data_in;
      my_ram[$random() % 4096] <= new_entry;
    end
  end

  else if (TYPE == type(ram_entry_short_t)) begin
    always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
      TYPE new_entry;
      new_entry.data_in <= data_in;
      my_ram[$random() % 4096] <= new_entry;
    end
  end

  else begin
    $error("Unsuported type ...");
  end

endmodule
```

You could replace the **if**/**else** cascade with a **case** to make the code slightly more readable. You could also refactor the initialization code a bit by extracting functions to avoid duplication.

You could also use `TYPE` as a port for your top module, instead of `data_in` and `opt_data_in`.

For option 2, you can leave your module signature as in your question and do all the magic inside:

```
module foo(clk, data_in, opt_data_in);
  parameter bit USE_OPT_IN = 1;

  input logic clk;
  input logic data_in;
  input logic opt_data_in;

  typedef struct packed {
    logic data_in;       
    logic opt_data_in;
  } ram_entry_full_t;

  typedef struct packed {
    logic data_in;       
  } ram_entry_short_t;

  if (USE_OPT_IN) begin
    always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
      ram_entry_full_t new_entry;
      new_entry.data_in <= data_in;
      new_entry.opt_data_in <= opt_data_in;
      my_ram[$random() % 4096] <= new_entry;
    end
  end

  else begin
    always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
      ram_entry_short_t new_entry;
      new_entry.data_in <= data_in;
      my_ram[$random() % 4096] <= new_entry;
    end
  end

endmodule
```

This way, it's impossible to instantiate your module with the wrong parameter and if you don't break interface compatibility if your module is already in use somewhere.

Comment: The problem is that this quickly becomes unreasonable. If I have 7 fields this is 128 structs I would need to implement. It's easier at this point to do:
`function int get_size();
    return 1 + USE_OPT_IN
endfunction
function logic get_data_opt_offset();
    return 0;
endfunction
function logic get_data_offset();
    return  get_data_opt_offset() + USE_OPT_IN;
endfunction
...
typedef logic [get_size() - 1] entry;
`

Comment: Depends on how much expressivity you're shooting for in the code. One might be easier to develop but more difficult to debug. Only you can make the call.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka since the code is not synthesizable in the first place, why not using svtb classes  with overloaded functions and inheritance? You might find a better solution there.

Comment: @Serge +1 for suggesting classes. The only counterargument I can think of is that they require a more expensive tool.